# How is a ruptured blood vessel repaired? (Drew Bledsoe)

Tags: treatment, surgery, hemorrhage

A famous near-fatal injury is the [ruptured blood vessel suffered by Drew Bledsoe in a football game in 2001](https://www.si.com/nfl/2016/09/22/drew-bledsoe-hit-tom-brady-mo-lewis-jets). He was hit in the chest by the tackler's shoulder and this sheared a blood vessel in his thoracic cavity. He began suffering hemothorax, which went initially unnoticed until a CAT scan was performed. Once the problem was recognized, the blood was drained and the hemorrhage stopped.

However, in accounts I have read of the incident, no description is given of the procedure used to solve the problem. In this kind of injury where an internal blood vessel has been cut or torn completely, how the injury treated?

Comment: If it's a large vessel the short answer would be surgery. Are you looking for surgical details or something else?

Comment: Blood also clots- smaller ruptured blood vessels will clot and heal on their own. In a situation like a hemothorax like you describe, sometimes the pressure in the cavity will also aid in hemostasis.